GLib.Variant For the Type String 'ai' Giving Error On First Run
Here is the code from a gnome extension:
try {
    log(``);
    global.set_persistent_state('int_val', GLib.Variant.new_int16(0));
    let state = global.get_persistent_state('n', 'int_val').get_int16();

    log(`State is ${state}`);

    global.set_persistent_state('array_of_int_val', GLib.Variant.new('ai', []));

    let marked = global.get_persistent_state('ai', 'array_of_int_val');

    log(`marked type is ${marked.get_type()}`);
    log(`marked str type is ${marked.get_type_string()}`);
    // let markedWindows = marked ? marked.unpack() : [];
} catch (error) {
    log(`${error}`);
}

Here is the log:
Run
State is 0
TypeError: marked is null
Run
State is 0
marked type is [boxed instance wrapper GIName: GLib.VariantType jsobj@0x2b068f887128 native @0x5595eeb15240]
marked str type is ai

When we are using GLib.Variant.new_int16(0), we are getting the value in first go but when we are using GLib.Variant.new('ai', []) it is giving error the first time and result the second time.
What might be the issue here. Is the code GLib.Variant.new('ai', []) correct.
I have also tried GLib.Variant.new('ai', "[]") and GLib.Variant.new('ai', '[]'). Same issue.
The following code also giving the same issue:
global.set_persistent_state('marked_windows', GLib.Variant.new_array(GLib.VariantType.new('i'), []));

What can be the solution here?

Can you clarify what you are trying to do? It's not clear what your goal is and what is not working.

HI andy, this was part of a code base in https://github.com/blueray453/gnome-utils-by-blueray453 . I removed set_persistent_state and get_persistent_state afterwards (because of this inconsistency). However, it will be great to know how not to get null the first time i call global.get_persistent_state('ai', 'array_of_int_val').

You'll have to show that code that doesn't work. I can't guess from where it used to be. The correct code for an array of integers is GLib.Variant.new('ai', [1, 2, 3]), that's all I can tell you.

Thank you very much Andy. What is the code for new empty array of integer. Would it be GLib.Variant.new('ai', [])?

Yes, that's correct.
